# CSS BRANDING TEMPLATE

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, branding

Am just getting started with css branding and i found out that the only way to make modification is by using the ID.

**1.Is there any css template available freely that i can just used.**

Branding is taking way too much time as i have to to style each single DOM element one by one(and am not a front end developer).

**2.Is there a better approach?**

Comment: depends on what you want branding. Full on branding or just colours. You can target class attribute too! Try out the design manager? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-design-manager-design-packages

Comment: @AliJafer full on  branding

Answer (score 0):

There are many CSS selectors not just ID, I would suggest you go through it, it won't take too much time.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: isnt there a template i can use?